# Eclipse plug-in: add controls to WizardNewProjectCreationPage

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, wizard

I was wondering if it is possible to add additional controls to the WizardNewProjectCreationPage. At this point it only has controls for a project name and location. I would like to keep these and add more to it.

I have seen the createControl method but I'm not sure how I can extend it without losing the controls already set by the WizardNewProjectCreationPage class and without having to rewrite the whole method again.

I forgot to add, that I have looked at a lot of tutorials and all of them discuss extending just a wizardPage and not a WizardNewProjectCreationPage in terms of controls.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are subclasses of WizardNewProjectCreationPage in Eclipse (such as NewProjectCreationPage).

I think you can extend the createControl method starting with this:

```
super.createControl(parent);    
Composite control = (Composite) getControl();
```

Then you can use 'control' to add the other controls.

Comment: I checked the Eclipse Help docs and it doesn't have any subclasses mentioned. But I will try this createControl method and post back.